# Issue creating view when the source table and column have the same name

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an Issue when trying to create view when the source table and column have the same name.
The view is created with wrong datatypes struct.
Reproduce:
Create table:

CREATE TABLE `database1`.newtable (a int, newtable string)
insert into `database1`.newtable values (1, "val")
Run:
select a,  newtable from `1111`.newtable
You will get 2 columns 1 int and the second one struct that contains 2 columns.
Is GBQ cannot distinction between column name and table name?
The question is why it behave like that is that a bug or by design ?

Rename to table or the column fixing the issue.
Using alias in the view are working with no issue.
The question is why it behave like that is that a bug or by design ?